# Jinja2 unzip list of tuples

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I unzip a list of tuples?
I have got

```
 x = [(1,'a'), (2, 'b')....]
```

And want to have

```
 x1 = [1,2..]
 x2 = ['a', 'b'...]
```

I have set a zip filter in my flask app but I am not sure is it a proper approach:

```
 app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
```

And in template

```
{% set x1, x2 = *x|zip %}
```

But there is also no * feature in jinja. How to solve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function that star unpacks its input into `zip`:

```
def unpack_and_zip(x):
    return zip(*x)
```

Then register that as your filter

```
app.jinja_env.filters['unpack_and_zip'] = unpack_and_zip

{% set x1, x2 = x|unpack_and_zip %}
```